# how to prevent entering to the site using url typing in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a site using CodeIgniter that is almost complete now.  My problem is that, even though I have implemented sessions and maintain a login system, a person can access any page by typing the URL into the browser address bar.

I have implemented the session for patient registration like this:

```
function index(){
    $this->is_logged_in();
}   

function log_out(){
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('login_controller');   
}

function is_logged_in(){
    $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');

    if(!isset($is_logged_in)||$is_logged_in!= TRUE ){
        redirect('login_controller');
    }else{
        $this->main();      
    }
}
```

Anonymous users can't acess the system just by typing the controller name like this:

> http://localhost/demo_site/index.php/register_controller

But they can do it like this:

> http://localhost/demo_site/index.php/register_controller/search_patient

Person can't access by typing the controller name, but can enter the system by typing a longer url than the controller, like the one shown above.

What is the problem here? What are the possible solutions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a routing problem. You need to set up your routes to make the second case illegal or at least map to the same controller as the first case. More on routing [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html).

Answer (score 8):

You will have to implement a login check in the controller's constructor.

Whenever the controller is called, it should check if the user is logged in - if they are not, redirect to a login page or an error page.

Comment: Second this. Put the logic in the controller's constructor...no need to make unique rules for all possible routes.

Answer (score 2):

To confirm if it is entering the login check put an `echo` and `exit` inside the `is_logged_in()` function and check if it appears in case of `http://localhost/demo_site/index.php/register_controller/search_patient`

You are probably doing login check in your respective modules and thus you missed for some cases.

It is better to define a set of private modules (say in an array) and do the login check in the frontcontroller itself (in one place) instead of repeatedly in module level.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with tHeSiD. This code should go in the constructor. Ideally in a base class which you use to extend all admin related or restricted classes with. Normally I use an Admin_Controller base class that extends CI_Controller (2.0) or Controller (1.7.x) and then create my application controllers by extending the Admin Controller.